# Save a CL image without exiting the environment

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I want to save a "snapshot" of the current environment so I can play with it later without consequences for messing it up. (Essentially creating a sandbox)

I know that I can save the image with `(save-lisp-and-die "sbcl.core")`. I also know that I can then load the image with `sbcl --core sbcl.core`.

The problem is that I have running threads that I cannot afford to stop even for a second and this command will exit `sbcl`.

My question is: **Can I create an image without exiting the environment?** I am looking for something like `(save-lisp "sbcl.core")`

If there is a portable way to do that - it would be great. If not - I am interested in a solution for SBCL.

Comment: Generally I would expect most implementations to stop all threads and to have the Lisp system be unresponsive while saving an image. With new systems it might not take that long. LispWorks for example can save 'sessions'. For that it halt all threads, closes the user interface / IDE, saves the session and then restarts the IDE. It doesn't leave the image, but the multiprocessing and the IDE will be restarted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SBCL core saving](https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2010/11/13/sbcl-core-saving/) gives the following function, based on [SBCL manual's advice](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Saving-a-Core-Image):

```
(defun save-core (core-fn)
  (progn
    #+sbcl
    (let ((fork-result (sb-posix:fork)))
      (case fork-result
        (-1 (error "fork failed"))
        (0 (sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die core-fn :toplevel #'main :executable t))
        (otherwise (sb-posix:wait)))
      (format t "stand-alone core ~a saved" core-fn))
    #-sbcl
    (error "not available on this lisp")
    (values)))
```

Unfortunately it might not work with running threads.

Comment: Why the error "not available on this lisp"? I use save-application on several other lisps.